# Encapsulating mutable states

Tags: f#

I'm working my way through the F# Wikibook and I have got to the section on reference cells, in which the following code snippet appears:

```
let incr =
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () ->
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter;;
```

This function is then called three times, giving the values 1, 2, and 3 respectively.  Can someone please explain why this function does not return 1 each time it is called? The way I interpret this code (which is obviously not the correct interpretation, hence the question) is that, first, the reference cell 'counter' is declared, with contents equal to `0`, then the contents of 'counter' is incremented by 1 and then dereferenced using the anonymous function. Since each call of `incr();;` declares 'counter' with contents `0`, I don't understand why calling `incr();;` doesn't simply return 1 each time.

Can anyone correct my understanding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it this way: `incr` is a *value*, not a function. Its value is a closure that captures some state (i.e., `counter`). It's the closure that is subsequently being called potentially multiple times (`incr` is only executed/assigned once). Maybe seeing the equivalent C# would help.

```cs
static Func<int> MakeCounter() {
    int counter = 0;
    return () => {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    };
}

var incr = MakeCounter();
incr(); //1
incr(); //2
incr(); //3
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that you can capture the mutable variable `counter` in a C# closure, whereas you need to explicitly make `counter` a heap allocated reference cell in F#.

Comment: @JohnReynolds See the blog post here: http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/on-lambdas-capture-and-mutability/ Using a mutable variable in that way can sometimes be difficult to reason about.  Forcing the use of a reference cell makes it more clear what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `incr()` you are invoking the value of `incr` which is the anonymous function on line 3. The code that is invoked is only the anonymous function, not all the lines in the definition of `incr`.

The initialisation of `counter` is only done once when `incr` is defined, not each time the value of `incr` is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

'incr' is a value rather than a function.
It instantiates 'counter' and then binds to the inner function (which closes over 'counter')

Invoking 'incr' is really invoking the inner function. 'counter' is only declared and instantiated once.